# perl code for file parsing

Tags: perl

how can i split a very large file into many small files on the basis of some pattern in a line of a file using `perl`.

Ex. file:

```
CONECT  592  593  594                                                           
CONECT  595  596  597                                                           
CONECT  597  598                                                                
END                
CONECT  591  593  594                                                           
CONECT  595  596  596                                                           
CONECT  597  598                                                                
END
CONECT  592  593  594                                                           
CONECT  594  596  598                                                           
CONECT  597  598                                                                
END
```

i have to make many seprate files fron the a single file. Output files start line should be '`CONECT`' & end line should be '`END`'. it is a large file (1gb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $file1='file_2b_read.txt';
my $File2='newfile_2b_created.txt';
open(CMD,  "<$file1") or die "$!";
open OUTPUT, ">$File2";
my  $cnt=1;
while(<CMD>) {

    print OUTPUT $_;    

    /^END/ and do {
        #create new file 
        $cnt++;
        close(OUTPUT);
        $File2='newfile_2b_created'.$cnt.'.txt';
        open OUTPUT, ">$File2";
        next;
    };
}
close(CMD);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

A little cleaner version with more modern perl usage (three parameter open with lexcial filehandles, error checking for calls to `open`)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file  = 'file_2b_read.txt';
my $out_file = 'newfile_2b_part_%06d.txt'; # Template for output filenames
my $counter  = 1;

open my $in_fh , '<' , $in_file or die $!;
open my $out_fh , '>' , sprintf( $out_file , $counter ) or die $!;

while( <$in_fh> ) {
  print $out_fh $_;

  if( /^END/ ) {
    close( $out_fh ) ;
    open $out_fh , '>' , sprintf( $out_file , ++$counter ) or die $!;
  }
}

# cleanup afterwards
close $out_fh ;
close $in_fh ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on dgw's answer but modified so that it will not create a spurious final file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file = 'file_2b_read.txt';
my $out_file_template = 'newfile_2b_part_%06d.txt';
my $counter = 1;

open my $in_fh , '<' , $in_file or die $!;
my $out_fh;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
    if (!$out_fh) {
        open $out_fh , '>' , sprintf( $out_file_template, $counter++ ) or die $!;
    }
    print $out_fh $_;

    if ( /^END/ ) {
        close( $out_fh );
        $out_fh = undef;
    }
}

# cleanup afterwards
if ($out_fh) { close( $out_fh ) }
close $in_fh;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small algo, you can try. Please let me know if you need any explicit code for it.

```
while (<FD>)
{
   if ($_ =~ /^END/)
   {
      # save buffer in new file.
      # reset buffer.
   }
   # add line to buffer.
}
```